ModuleNotFoundError: no module named ... when submitting job to client with an object from that module
I have a weird issue I am not able to solve.
I have created a Local dask client, and I have a preload script that imports local modules. The preload script contains a list of paths, and runs sys.path.append(path) for each path in the dictionary. I then import my modules import mod1 which live at those parts. The preload script works fine and I can see it imports successfully as if I add print(mod1.obj), I see that in the logs.
However, when submitting a job to the client like this:
def job(param):
    return mod1.obj

fut = client.submit(job, 'asd')
fut.result()

This gives a ModuleNotFoundError: no module named mod1
The bottom 2 levels in the stack trace is
pickle.py - return pickle.loads(x) and then
cloudpickle.py - __import__(name)
If I import the module in my function, it works:
def job(param):
    import mod1
    return mod1.obj
fut = client.submit(job, 'asd')
fut.result()

However, if I need to pass the object as an argument, and with an import it still doesn't work
def job(param):
    import mod1
    return param
fut = client.submit(job, mod1.obj)
fut.result()

For this function, the stack trace ends at
pickle.py - return pickle.loads(x)
My preload script is exactly the same as what is at the top of my client script I use to call the client

Hard to tell without a complete stack trace, but what you describe might be due to a problem of serialization of your module or the object contained. Can you do a pickle.dump and pickle load on this module?
